# Cmake configuration error, CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo

Tags: cmake, azerothcore

I am using windows 10 and have followed classic installation using the latest git bash inside the folder I want using option(1) copying the git text to the git bash and the cloning went normal no errors, I have also downloaded the latest CMake x64 version and followed the guide exactly and after I choose vs 15(2017) and hit finish I have an error message saying error in the configuration process, "project files may be invalid"

I already had git and CMake and all versions of vs installed but to make sure I redownloaded the newest versions and tried again no luck, I also recloned the repository no luck. after the error pops up there is a list item in CMake with name:CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES value:Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo

Any help appreciated, if I figure it out I will update this thanks.

Comment: I also noticed in the cmake logs that it says amd64 which is incorrect as i have an i7

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, the pathing to my visual studio 15 2017 was incorrect, thanks peeps.